# Add token to the header of Vimeo API Android

Tags: android, vimeo, vimeo-api, vimeo-android

First of all, sorry for my english, thanks if you edit my question.
I need to use my admin account to access for videos on my app.
So i must send my token on the header, the docs said:

> curl -H "Authorization: bearer OAUTH_TOKEN" https://api.vimeo.com

But i cant do this on Java, this is my method:

> public Call fetchContent(String uri, CacheControl cacheControl, ModelCallback callback,
>                                    @Nullable String query, @Nullable Map refinementMap,
>                                    @Nullable String fieldFilter)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with [version 1.0.1](https://github.com/vimeo/vimeo-networking-java/releases/tag/1.0.1) of the vimeo-networking library. If you refer to the new section in the [README](https://github.com/vimeo/vimeo-networking-java#configuration-builder-for-apps-with-only-one-developer-account) as well as the [sample app](https://github.com/vimeo/vimeo-networking-java/blob/1.0.1/example/src/main/java/com/vimeo/android/networking/example/TestApp.java), it will cover how to initialize the `VimeoClient` instance with an oAuth Token (or "access token") provided by the developer console.

`VimeoClient.initialize(new Configuration.Builder(<accessToken>).build());`

You can alternately initialize the builder with the client id and client secret and then set the access token on the builder with `setAccessToken(<accessToken>)` if you want to also allow for code grant authentication.

Setting this access token on the builder will default all requests to use that token. If you've provide the client id and client secret, then users of your app could authenticate with a code grant authentication. This will overwrite your initially provided "access token" and all future requests will use their token.

Full disclosure: I'm one of the authors of this library. We also highly encourage any issues or feature requests to be filed [here](https://github.com/vimeo/vimeo-networking-java/issues).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have another problem, Its possible to get a token with a custom login? On the api exists the method login(user,pw,callback) but i always get error.
 error:Something strange occurred. Please contact the app owners

Comment: @pcg26 That login method is only available to certain applications with certain privileges. You can get a token for a custom login, but you'll have to do it through a "code grant redirect". [This guide](https://github.com/vimeo/vimeo-networking-java#oauth-authorization-code-grant) explains how to do it in on Android and [this guide](https://developer.vimeo.com/api/authentication#generate-redirect) explains how it works on the API.
The idea is - a user will click a login button. It brings them to web. They log in on our website. Then we direct them back to your app.

Answer (score 1):

Use HttpURLConnection and pass OAUTH_TOKEN in the header

```
String oAuthToken = "your-token";
HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
URL vimeoURL = new URL("https://api.vimeo.com");
try {
    urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) vimeoURL.openConnection();
    // set authentication
    String auth = "Bearer " + oAuthToken;
    urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Authorization", auth.trim());
    // set request method
    urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
    if (urlConnection.getResponseCode() == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
         // do something
    }
  } catch (Exception e) {// append e
        // do something
  } finally {
      if (urlConnection != null) {// close connection
         urlConnection.disconnect();
     }
  }
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, yes your code works, but i need to use the api request to cache and serialize the response.
I tried with volley and i cant cache it. Maybe the header, idk.

Comment: ohok I thought you want to know how to send OAUTH-Token in a header. Check out https://github.com/vimeo/vimeo-networking-java/blob/dev/vimeo-networking/src/main/java/com/vimeo/networking/VimeoClient.java#L926

Comment: yes i need to send a token in a header! but using the vimeo api networking.
Maybe creating a user?

Comment: yeah you would have to create a user to get the token. OAUTH-TOKEN would be for a user. Its used for authentication.

Comment: yes i know, but i have a token created on the vimeo web. Then i need to use that token to get all the private videos. Only for this query, then i wanna use the user token. Do you understand me? :D