# Vimeo method login networking api Android

Tags: android, vimeo, vimeo-api, vimeo-android

First of all, sorry for my english, edit my post is wellcome :D
Its possible to get a token with this method?
My boss said that the WebView login of vimeo is bad because its difficult to see the button "Allow".

So, im trying to do a custom login interface sending the email and password.

```
public Call<VimeoAccount> logIn(String email, String password, AuthCallback callback) {
```

But Im always getting this error:

> Something strange occurred. Please contact the app owners

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just responded to your comment on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36046335/1759443):

> That login method is only available to certain applications with certain privileges. You can get a token for a custom login, but you'll have to do it through a "code grant redirect". This guide explains how to do it in on Android and this guide explains how it works on the API. The idea is - a user will click a login button. It brings them to web. They log in on our website. Then we direct them back to your app.

The reason we use redirect is because it would be a security concern if developers of applications could see the passwords of Vimeo users. So for the time being, the only way to authenticate with the Vimeo API is through a code grant redirect (as specified in the quoted comment). This means you'll have to link out to a browser/webview.

*Edit*

For others, the official Vimeo Android SDK is [here](https://github.com/vimeo/vimeo-networking-java).

Comment: want to update this answer with the new access token info? https://github.com/vimeo/vimeo-networking-java

Comment: Yeah this is a duplicate question, all of the details should be at this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36018865/add-token-to-the-header-of-vimeo-api-android/36046335#36046335