# Vimeo Java API (Clickntap)

Tags: java, vimeo, vimeo-api

I'm using the Clickntap Java API for Vimeo and it's saying error http 403 when I try the example class which they provided. 
Do I need something more than the token for uploading? Do you know any other Java API for vimeo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have access token generated on vimeo and you using that access token, that should be enough.Once you include **clickntap** library into your project, you can do this.

```
public class UploadFile {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String accesstoken ="abc";
        Vimeo vimeo = new Vimeo(accesstoken);
        boolean upgradeTo1080 = true;
        try {
            String videoEndPoint = vimeo.addVideo(new File(pathtoyourvideo), upgradeTo1080);
            System.out.println(videoEndPoint);
        } catch (IOException | VimeoException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

in `vimeo.addVideo()` method library set to perform authentication using access token and upload video. You can customize options as well. This is very trivial library compared to vimeo own library, which is not very easy use by average programmer.

Comment: Do you recommend **Clickntap** or **Scribe** ? I found these two libraries as good ones.

Comment: Looks like `Scribe` is only auth provider. The only issue with `clickntap` is no async callback mechanism to make async calls to get the progress information when we are uploading video.

Comment: You got it! Thanks for the tips.

Answer (score 0):

I can't really speak to the Clickntap library since I've never used it. But the official Vimeo Java API github can be found [here (`vimeo-networking-java`)](https://github.com/vimeo/vimeo-networking-java). The README is pretty extensive and should cover obtaining an auth token. It doesn't have upload APIs as of right now, but we'll be releasing a library for that in the future. In the mean time, you can use `vimeo-networking-java` in unison with the [developer docs](https://developer.vimeo.com/api/upload/videos) for upload.

But basically, you'll just need the token as well as specifying that you require the `upload` scope. You need to request the access to this scope from your [Vimeo developer account](https://developer.vimeo.com/apps).

Refer to the answer on [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36046335/1759443) on how to easily set up an access token.

Comment: I've already saw this offcial Vimeo Java API, but the problem is, this is an Android SDK. The Guidelines says it can be uploaded and get informations about the videos by REST, but now you said don't have it... Can you provide more information?

Comment: @JulioC.Boll.. They have java library as well, but it's very complex with very little documentation. Worst thing about Vimeo API is they don't bother to provide some examples on how to use, especially when its a commercial service.

Comment: Julio - Only the example app is written in Android, the library itself is exclusively Java. vimeo-networking-java doesn't have full coverage of our API yet. Our API supports upload, the java library currently does not (but it will in the future).
@SRy Please [file any issues](https://github.com/vimeo/vimeo-networking-java/issues) you have on our github. We're actively improving the library/responding to feedback, which is another reason we suggest you use our official java library. We strive to update it as the API changes.

Comment: @Kyle...Thanks for addressing my concern. My only issue while I tried to use Vimeo Java networking library is I am not able to figure out where to include file that I want to upload in the request in PUT method . An example would be great.

Comment: @Kyle...Thanks for yours adivises, if you can share some examples, all the community will be glad.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback guys. I've just added an issues to our [issue tracker](https://github.com/vimeo/vimeo-networking-java/issues) which will hopefully address your concerns. Please feel free to add additional comments to help clarify any and all needs.