# Do a query for vimeo files problem getting Json

Tags: android, api, vimeo, vimeo-player, vimeo-android

I have the following URL https://api.vimeo.com/search?from=me&q=test but when i try access it tells me no user credentials where provided. i already made a token with all the fields including private and public and also the other spaces.So in this URL where and how should i add the token? I found in some documentation that said that this link https://vimeo.com/search?q=Mazda+2 will also work for api.vimeo.com/search?q....... what i want is to integrate in my android app depending on the selected it in a recyclerView do a query according to the name of the item to put it at the end of https://vimeo.com/search?q= (Name of the item) and then show the results in a Listview for the user to select which videos they could see.
And then play the video selected.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is very general, vimeo uses OAuth 2.0, you have to decide what type of token you need for public or private content, depending on it your authentication workflow will change.

You should first study the [authentication documentation](https://developer.vimeo.com/api/authentication) of the vimeo api.

Comment: Yes i have already tried it with different tokens one with public , but this doesnt answer my question where in the url do i put the token?

Comment: Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36018865/add-token-to-the-header-of-vimeo-api-android/36046335#36046335) can help.